# dashboard and dashlets drag and drop broken. can drop any dashlet in dashboard

Tags: reports, dashboard, dashlet

Good morning,

I'm new to Civicrm and I'm hooked! I was configuring the reports and dashlets for the Civicrm dashboard.
At first everything was fine, but I decided to remove all the dashlets I already had in the dashboard to add the ones I needed.
Since I removed them, I can't drop them on the dashboard anymore... I see all the dashlets and I can move them, but I can't drop them anywhere and I don't see any column where to drop them (according to the civi manuals).
I'm stuck, I don't know what else to try, does anyone have the same problem? I work with wordpress.

Cheers to the community, you guys are awesome.

Translated with [www.DeepL.com/Translator](http://www.DeepL.com/Translator) (free version)

Comment: Can you check the browser's dev console/network tab for errors?

Comment: The following error is displayed in the console: 
DevTools failed to load source map: Could not load content for https://www.eapcnet.eu/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/persist/contribute/dyn/dc.min.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE

I don't know if it has to do with it, but I still can't move the dashlets because there is no column to put them in.
I don't know if anyone has had the same problem?

Comment: That error is normal. It's not really an error. I don't know what would cause the drag and drop problem but there must be some javascript not loading.

Comment: and what can i do?

Comment: @Demerit what can i do?

Answer (score 2):

For me it's been an issue of the Finsbury Park Theme:
https://lab.civicrm.org/extensions/finsburypark

It doesn't occur on the default Theme and Shoreditch.