# dashlets drag and drop broke. no columns to drag

Tags: dashboard, dashlet

Good morning,

I'm new to Civicrm and I'm hooked! I was configuring the reports and dashlets for the Civicrm dashboard. At first everything was fine, but I decided to remove all the dashlets I already had in the dashboard to add the ones I needed. Since I removed them, I can't drop them on the dashboard anymore... I see all the dashlets and I can move them, but I can't drop them anywhere and I don't see any column where to drop them (according to the civi manuals). I'm stuck, I don't know what else to try, does anyone have the same problem? I work with wordpress.

Cheers to the community, you guys are awesome.

Comment: Is this the same as your other question? https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/42998/dashboard-and-dashlets-drag-and-drop-broken-can-drop-any-dashlet-in-dashboard

Comment: Does this answer your question? [dashboard and dashlets drag and drop broken. can drop any dashlet in dashboard](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/42998/dashboard-and-dashlets-drag-and-drop-broken-can-drop-any-dashlet-in-dashboard)